# _id and Number not accessing using query : Android

Tags: android

my code is as following

```
String projection[] = new String[]{ ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, //The URI, using the content:// scheme, for the content to retrieve.
                        projection,             // projection
                        null,               // selection
                        null,               // selectionArgs
                        ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
```

I want to add contact id, name and number (MAIN or any one of type) to intent, but problem is that I am unable to access Name. And another problem is that for each contact id returns "-1". why? 
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead off supplying the value of `projection` variable as `null` in the `query` method you should try it like this:

```
String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data._ID,
                                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
                                    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
```

It is clearly written in Android Developer Documentation that:

> Adapter that exposes data from a Cursor to a **ListView** widget. The **Cursor** must include a column named **"_id"** or this class will not work.

See here in the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Comment: I added projection but are you sure about NUMBER, because till I couldn't access Number (contact number). Some articles says that Number stored on their own table so we have to make query with _ID. I mean I have to write to query method. I follow this way and I got NUMBER, but is there any other way to get contact number, using a single query ( as you given).

Comment: @Pankaj: yes u can do it by writing a single query. Use this value of projection `String[] projection = new String[] { Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };` also don't forget to import `android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` class

Comment: ok, this is projection. But how to access those numbers (like contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)))for accessing name.

Comment: @Pankj: like this: `String phoneNumber = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));`